# In jmeter unable to run some APIs for specific time duration

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, threadgroup

I am running load test of 2 hours in jmeter. In my jmeter script there are 4 APIs that will run successfully for 30 mins only, after that they will fail, and others can run for 2 hours. I want that once execution is started all APIs will start running simultaneously, after 30 mins those 4 APIs will stop automatically, and for the rest 1 hour 30 mins others will keep running. How to achieve this on script level.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your "APIs" (whatever it is) into different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and set different durations for the thread groups.

[image]

If you prefer to have only 1 Thread Group you can go for [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) instead and run its children only for first 30 minutes of the test

[image]